# How to create a lookup

Tags: r, shiny, lookup-tables

I currently have a Shiny app in which you can upload a csv file and it will 
show you the data. 
I want to add a search bar where you can search for specific rows based on 
three variables. 
I then want these rows that I have searched for and then selected to form a 
new downloadable csv. 
Is this possible?

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)
    library(DT)
    library(dplyr)
    library(data.table)
    #I don't need all these packages just yet but I will use them as I carry on the project hopefully
    ui = fluidPage(
      fileInput("Rams","Upload complete list of Rams", accept=".csv"),  

    #fileinput where a list of rams (male sheep) are loaded. I want to select a 
    few rams from the list based on their unique combinations of birth year, tag 
    number and flock number

      br(),
      DT::dataTableOutput("Rams1")
    )

    server = function(input, output, session) {
    #server section of my app  
    #This shows me the data
    output$Rams1 <- renderDataTable({
      Rams2 <- input$Rams
      if (is.null(Rams2))
        return(NULL)
      subset(read.csv(Rams2$datapath, header=T, sep=","))
    })

    }

    shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[Even if I simply select 3 rows as done here, all 15 rows are shown in the downloaded file as shown in the next picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfHhU.png)

[The downloaded file simply produces all data rather than just the ones I am filtering for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSEpn.png)

Comment: Yes its possible. You can save the filtered data in `reactiveValues` and download that as a csv

Answer (score 0):

Below code will solve the problem

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
#I don't need all these packages just yet but I will use them as I carry on the project hopefully
ui = fluidPage(
  fileInput("Rams","Upload complete list of Rams", accept=".csv"),  
  br(),
  DT::dataTableOutput("Rams1"),downloadButton(outputId = "download_filtered",
                                              label = "Download Filtered Data")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    infile <- input$Rams
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })

  output$Rams1 = DT::renderDataTable(datatable(datasetInput() ,filter = "top"),
  server = FALSE)


  output$download_filtered <- 
    downloadHandler(
      filename = "Filtered Data.csv",
      content = function(file){
        write.csv(datasetInput()[input[["Rams1_rows_all"]], ],
                  file)
      })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you very much for your input. Very helpful.

Comment: I have a couple more questions: the downloaded data set has all the values not just the selected rows.. how do I change this? Also, the downloaded data now is enclosed by quotes followed by a comma, can I eradicate the quotes somehow? Also, for non-numeric variables how do I get a search bar where you type in the search rather than use the slider. @RahulAgarwal

Comment: Hi, the downloaded set have only the rows filtered by you in the search box of DT datatable (Image 1 shows 28/1470 entries on my some filtered results). And when I am downloading it is just a normal csv with only the filtered set. For any column (numeric or non-numeric), I get both search bar and text box. So, I can either use slider or use text bar (Shown in image 2). The above code works perfectly on my system and on various data sets I have used

Comment: Avinash Shasti: I hope the updated answer has solved problem

Comment: Everything except the downloadHandler function is working properly, somebody please help! **:,-(**

Comment: Just a little caution, in my download function: write.csv(datasetInput()[input[["Rams1_rows_all"]], ], "datasetinput()" is the function where the uploaded file is read and stored, "Rams1" is the name of datatableoutput i have given in UI. Please see, you are replicating the same, there can be some mistakes